# React redirects to home page on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

When a user refresh current page, react redirects it to home page. How do I prevent this? On force refresh page url should not change. I have tried HashRouter also, but no luck. can someone please suggest me what I am doing wrong ?

Versions that I am using

```
"react": "^16.11.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import BaseRouter from './routes';
import CustomLayout from './containers/Layout';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
            <CustomLayout {...this.props}>
              <BaseRouter />
            </CustomLayout>
          </Router>

        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

here is part of routes.js

```
        <React.Fragment>
            {!token ? <Redirect to='/login/' /> :
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                    <Route exact path='/customers/' component={Customers} />
                    <Route exact path='/some-route/' component={someRoute} />
                    <Route component={Page404} />
                </Switch>
            }
        </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: When you refresh the page your `token` in `routes.js` might get `false`.

Comment: I guess no, I tried removing it too but  No luck

Comment: Can you show the code where you take the token?